# Are there Collections in javascript?

Tags: javascript, collections

Currently I am studying data structures and algorithms.
Having more experience in javascript, I feel more convenient in coding in Javascript.

Although, if I want to go deeper inside building strong algorithms, I believe using collections is very important.

This is the main reason I want to know if there are Collections in javascript.

Comment: If you have experience in Javascript, I believe you are able to perform a research on Google ;-) Asking external resource (Book, tutorial, API, ..) is off-topic on SO

Comment: you can have collections defined in Javascript libraries. But i don't think Javascript has collections.

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Don't stop with JS, go ahead to the lovely C.

Answer (score 3):

Yes we do have collection in Javascript. Those are Array, Map, WeakMap and Set.

Those are well documented in MDN.
[Keyed Collections in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections) 
and 
[Indexed Collections in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections)

Comment: Is it something like `var tiles = document.getElementById("myID);` a type of collection?